# MySQL backup - incremental and differential

Tags: server, backup, mysql

How can I backup MySQL database incrementally and differentially ?

Does anyone have a script or recommended application for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/path/to/targetdir --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
```

You may need to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install xtrabackup
```

Comment: Did you address the "incremental and differential" part of the question?

Comment: Yes. Xtrabackup is incremental